# Why are all images be changed to the first input

Tags: javascript, image, thumbnails

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var interval; 
    $('#105').mouseover(function()
    { mouseOver('105'); });
    $('#105').mouseout(function()
    { mouseOut('105') ;});
    function mouseOver(videoId) 
    {   var num = 2;
        interval = setInterval(function() 
        { $('#'+videoId).attr('src', '../thumbs/268255615/268255615.'+num+'.jpg');
        if(num == 12)
        { num = 1; }
        else
        { num++; }},500);   }
    function mouseOut (videoId)
    { clearInterval(interval); $('#'+videoId).attr('src', '../thumbs/268255615/268255615.1.jpg'); } 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var interval; 
    $('#104').mouseover(function()
    { mouseOver('104'); });
    $('#104').mouseout(function()
    { mouseOut('104') ;});
    function mouseOver(videoId) 
    {   var num = 2;
        interval = setInterval(function() 
        { $('#'+videoId).attr('src', '../thumbs/325082397/325082397.'+num+'.jpg');
        if(num == 12)
        { num = 1; }
        else
        { num++; }},500);   }
    function mouseOut (videoId)
    { clearInterval(interval); $('#'+videoId).attr('src', '../thumbs/325082397/325082397.1.jpg'); } 
</script>
```

The code above is a JavaScript image rotator. The problem with the code is that the last image path always overwrites the image paths before it.

For example if image `path one = thumbs/imagea.jpg` and if `path two = thumbs/imageb.jpg` path one ("thumbs/imagea.jpg")then becomes path two on hover becomes ("thumbs/imageb.jpg")

This script worked at one point trying to figure out what is wrong or been changed any ideas?

Comment: using 2 identical `var interval;` may be a problem here. Because you have only 1 variable being accessed by 2 functions `clearInterval(interval);`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite obvious: you are redefining mouseOver as a function. The second time you define it, it overwrites the first function. This is because mouseOver is defined on window-scope. Splitting it up in two  blocks does not change that. Also note that "interval" is also being defined twice, so a name clash will also occur here.

A solution would be to either use closures, change the name of one of either functions or merge the two functions into one.

Closures are done by wrapping each script in the following block:

```
(function() {
  // your script here
}());
```

A merged function would be:

```
var i, setupImage, images;
images = [
    { "id" : "#104", "prefix" : "../thumbs/325082397/325082397." },
    { "id" : "#105", "prefix" : "../thumbs/268255615/268255615." }
];

setupImage = function (image) {
    'use strict';
    var interval;
    $(image.id).mouseover(function () {
        var num = 2;
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $(image.id).attr('src', image.prefix + num + '.jpg');
            if (num === 12) {
                num = 1;
            } else {
                num += 1;
            }
        }, 500);
    });
    $(image.id).mouseout(function () {
        $(image.id).mouseout(function () {
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(image.id).attr('src', image.prefix + '1.jpg');
        });
    });
};

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
    setupImage(images[i]);
}
```